# Is it possible to somehow define a material or brush that completely ignores the current lighting?

Tags: wpf, graphics, 3d

I have a model that looks good with lighting, but in that model I want to add a 3D-surface-graph that looks best if I turn lighting off. Does anyone know if it is possible to make the light affect only a selection of objects in my scene?

The best I have come up with so far is to combine a DiffuseMaterial and an EmissiveMaterial with the same color, but that results in some strange visual effects so it’s far from perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are no lights you will not see the object.

If you want to have a different set of lights for a specific object just put the object in a separate Model3DGroup with its own lights.